# Tree View of a Data Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to implement some tree like that in ASP.NET: [alt text http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/w6ws38fw.vbVenusSiteNavigation_TreeView1(en-us,VS.100).gif](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/w6ws38fw.vbVenusSiteNavigation_TreeView1(en-us,VS.100).gif)

However, this is a TreeView component in the Navigation Tab. I want a DataGrid in a tree view which isn't navigation. Is there a ready FREE component out there?? If not, what is the right component to start with to build such a tree component???

I'm not in a hurry, it will be better for me if I can build my own, but I want to know the component to start with?is it the DataGrid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't get hung up on the fact that it appears in the Navigation tab in the Toolbox - there's nothing to stop you using the `<asp:treeview>` to represent another hierarchical structure. Have a look at the [Treeview Quickstart tutorial](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/navigation/treeview.aspx) which covers using it for data as well as navigation.